# arcgis custom places loaded from file or db

Tags: javascript, json, database, file, arcgis-js-api

Hello since Google maps can load custom places from .xml file, what about Arcgis, I found that they have example, but its saved in .json format, while i retrieved their example .json and put on my local server seems it can't load, so how to load custom places using Arcgis? Example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=fl_featureCollection

Comment: Do you see any specific errors in the Console tab or network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Well enabled these mime types: 
application/vnd.geo+json
application/geo+json
what to do next? My server is Xampp